# ::ng-deep angular 6 style pierce ngx-chips tag-input component

Tags: sass, angular6

Having major trouble trying to change simple style properties of this ngx-chips tags input component.

Looked up the documentation to find out that I have to do :ng-deep to the tags to change the styling https://github.com/gbuomprisco/ngx-chips/blob/master/docs/custom-themes.md

Problem is, their suggestion did not work.

Realized that the right way to use this method is ::ng-deep, not :ng-deep. But that still did not work.

I was able to go to my browser and directly change my styling, but can't seem to do this with my scss code.

Here is my scss styling:

```
// apply theme to the tags
::ng-deep .ng2-tag-input.bootstrap tag {
   align-items: center !important;
   background: #63c2de !important;
}
```

Here are the tags associated to the ngx-chips component

```
      <tag-input formControlName="tags" theme="bootstrap">
        <tag-input-dropdown [autocompleteItems]="uniqueTags" [matchingFn]="matchingFn">
        </tag-input-dropdown>
      </tag-input>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a look in you **scss** you have used this ...

```
::ng-deep .ng2-tag-input.bootstrap tag { ... }
```

In you code you haven't give any class. Please check that. If all the thing is right then try this also.

```
:host ::ng-deep .ng2-tag-input.bootstrap tag { ... }
```

Here you should use `:host` to apply your css.

**Note:** `:host` will work on that component only in which you have used `:host`.

Comment: doesn't work, do i have to reference tag-input somewhere?

Comment: `<tag-input formControlName="tags" theme="bootstrap" class="tag">`this way you have to give class ... and use this tag class in scss. Use another class in dropdown also.